# Copied git repository from one machine to the next, now I get repo error. How do I fix it?

Tags: git

I just bought a new computer. On my old machine I had an XCode project that was cloned from a remote repo on BitBucket.

I decided to copy the physical git project folder/files from my old machine to my new machine.

I did some work in XCode in my_branch and was able to stage and check in to the local git repo on my new machine.

Now when I tried to 'git push my_branch origin'  get the error...

```
fatal: 'my_branch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What did I do wrong? What should I have done?
Is it because I didn't setup the public/private keys between my new machine and BitBucket? I thought I did this but maybe I didn't do it correctly.

Comment: Try `git help push`. The first argument is the repository to push to, not a branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do it right, than it should work:

```
git push [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

so `git push origin my_branch` should do the trick!

Comment: {Hand slapping forehead}! Thanks @phoet.