# Patching folder inside a Git repo - error: Not a git repository

Tags: android, git, repository

I have done

```
$ cd android4.3
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.3
$ repo sync
```

and have a full copy of android source, I now wish to run a patch on the /frameworks/opt folder and am getting "fatal: not a git repository" 
It is true that there is no .git folder in the /frameworks/opt directory but there is a .repo folder in the android4.3
I have in the past run patches on /frameworks/base (and others) and can still rebase and repatch it. There is a .git folder there that was already there. I'm not sure how it got there I just know I didn't add it.

I have installed a new HD and a new ubuntu on it and am running from that but accessing the old files on the old drive. I do not wish to redownload the repo if it can at all be avoided as it is over 20Gb and I would have to repatch etc.

My question is, what do I need to do to get the repo to act as if it was initialised on this installation or has the move even caused it to act differently?
I have tried to do a `$ git init` in the /opt folder, but as I didn't need to do this for the other patches I am uncertain whether this is linked to the .repo in the parent directory.
As I realised I would have to manually add the files in /opt I felt that it is not.

I have run `$ repo status` and it comes back fine apart from a few files gedit left over (~)

If I run repo sync it will discard all my changes won't it?

I know there is another question [Copied git repository...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452670/copied-git-repository-from-one-machine-to-the-next-now-i-get-repo-error-how-do) here but it does not quite cover my requirements. I have also found [Android repo manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149725/how-does-the-android-repo-manifest-repository-work). which is great but I'm still unsure.

It is the sheer size of the download that is making me reluctant to test this out with out more knowledge.

Comment: OK working on an external partition makes no difference.
All I needed to do is 

    `$ git init`
    `$ git add .`

At this point I found the subdirectories contained .git folders.
so I removed the .git folders from all the subdirectories although I could have patched the sub project directly as the patch only updated one of them.

Anyway, I got it going. 
Hope this helps someone in the future. p.s. I am unable to answer my own question. or I would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK working on an external partition makes no difference. All I needed to do is $ git init $ git add . At this point I found the subdirectories contained .git folders. so I removed the .git folders from all the subdirectories although I could have patched the sub project directly as the patch only updated one of them. Anyway, I got it going. Hope this helps someone in the future.